# Nginx Too Many Redirects with cookie value

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, cookies

I seem to be missing something here, I am getting a redirect loop with the following configuration. The goal is to look for a cookie and its value and use a different upstream if value2 exists.

```
#== UPSTREAMS ==
upstream server_vip {
    server superduper.com:443;
}

upstream server_alt_vip {
    server superduper2.com:443;
}
    map $cookie_route_parallel $pool { 
        default "server_vip";
        value2 "server_alt_vip";
        value1 "server_vip";
    }
        location /directory {
            proxy_pass https://$pool/directory;
```

Comment: I also tried: 

map $cookie_route_parallel $pool {
        default "superduper.com:443";
        value2 "superduper2.com:443";
        value1 "superduper.com:443";
    }

And adding resolvers to the locations but getting :

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and the access log is full of 301s.

Comment: There is no redirect in this piece of config.

Comment: @AlexeyTen precisely. Yet, the access logs with this change have nothing but 301s:

10.16.80.10 - [11/Dec/2023:14:22:57 -0800] "GET /directory/ HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "https://referringdomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-" "superduper.com:443"

Comment: You shoud show full nginx config. And make sure that it's not an upstream that send redirect.